# one way web/socket/tcp/whatever request, is this possible, doesnt have to be in a browser

Tags: http, sockets, networking, tcp

I hope i will explain my question correctly.

I would like to make a request, to a url or a entity that lives at some port or address

and whatever is listening at that port will take the request and run with it, but will not
respond at all and neither will the client wait for the response, it will continue doing what needs to be done next,

the server or whatever is listening on that port will do what instructions i layed out in the request and that is it, i do not need confirmation whether what i wanted done got done

is this possible?

if i could sum up my questions it would be how can i make non-blocking to the client http requests to a listener on a remote host

if it is not possible, please explain to me why in short or point me where i could find this info.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol, fits your requirements?

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal Not if he wants HTTP.

Comment: Just make a REST call to the server but don't wait for the response. Just ignore it or return null from the server. Does it have to go to a tcp/udp address and port or can you handle that on your server side and just make a REST call to your server side?

Comment: so from your comments i take it that i cannot make a non blocking request to a port from any code that runs in the browser viewport, the only way to make these sort of requests is to code my own udp requests in some language that supports those requests

Comment: i know about async in javascript, but that still waits for a response, and i don't want to ignore it, i'm interested in the listener not serving the request with a response, just doing what i told it to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. HTTP is a request/response protocol.

Comment: The OP would be much better off learning how to deal with HTTP responses in a non-blocking manner (i.e. threading or multiprocessing)

Comment: @MikePennington OP clearly states there is no response. Non-blocking mode, multi-threading, etc., would therefore be futile.

Answer (score -1):

yeah, when you run -

```
 http.get(myUrl)
```

with a callback missing, the computer sits around waiting for the response anyway. It's kinda weird, but it's a tenet of HTTP.

you may be interested in [UDP](https://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-udp-server-and-client-example.html), which is more "fire-and-forget", and [somewhat similar](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_udp_datagram_sockets) in the node API. (It's got some gotchas though too!)